# How to get the two different text which is not known by user in same intent using alexa and dialog flow

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es, alexa-slot

I am working with alexa and dialog flow.
I want to get the title and description from user.
I have implemented @sys.any in same intent.
Help me to get the dynamic changing value from user for multiple times in same intent

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue. For Amazon alexa if you just want free text responded by the user then you can us AMAZON.SearchQuery. For more details https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery

Comment: I used AMAZON.SearchQuery.The value is assigned to description when am assigning the value for title.How to assign the value for title and description.I am using multiple SearchQuery.The corresponding value is not assigning correctly

Comment: Please make sure that your skill uses no more than one AMAZON.SearchQuery slot per intent and also you cannot have 2 intent with this utterance like {Query}

Comment: Ruby, consider adding the relevant portion of the interaction model to the question, and give example of utterances and how you expect to receive them in your skill